# How to bulid a url string with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm sending a url and get a json back.But the url has many parameters, about 10 parameters, like below.

https://faceplusplus.com/api/?key=00000000000000&q=flowers&tags=photo&lang=en&pretty=true

The parameter "q" has many values, users may change the valus as they want, so does other parameters.

How to build the url with a clean way?

Comment: Can you show the current code that you are using to build this URL?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: The [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent) class provides the basic building blocks for that, seeing as you are likely POSTing an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request.